# Is there a way to stop Azure ML throwing an error when exporting zero lines of data?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently developing an Azure ML pipeline that as one of its outputs is maintaining a SQL table holding all of the unique items that are fed into it. There is no way to know in advance if the data fed into the pipeline is new unique items or repeats of previous items, so before updating the table that it maintains it pulls the data already in that table and drops any of the new items that already appear.

However, due to this there are cases where this self-reference results in zero new items being found, and as such there is nothing to export to the SQL table. When this happens Azure ML throws an error, as it is considered an error for there to be zero lines of data to export. In my case, however, this is expected behaviour, and as such absolutely fine.

Is there any way for me to suppress this error, so that when it has zero lines of data to export it just skips the export module and moves on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by an update to Azure Machine Learning; You can now run pipelines with a flag set to "Continue on Failure Step", which means that steps following the failed data export will continue to run.

This does mean you will need to design your pipeline to be able to handles upstream failures in its downstream modules; this must be done very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are struggling to orchestrate a data pipeline because there orchestration is happening in two places. My advice would be to either move more orchestration into Azure ML, or make the separation between the two greater. One way to do this would be to have a regular export to blob of the table you want to use as training. Then you can use a Logic App to trigger a pipeline whenever a non-empty blob lands in the location